# Angular, render something depending if this array id exist in another array

Tags: angular

I have two arrays that I got back.
I will call them AllProjects and CurrentEmployeeProjects.

[image]

Now on  my Angular, I want to render all the projects, and on each project, if the employee has that project, it will render eg.DeleteButton, if the employee does not have the project, it will render eg.AllButton

```
<div class="cards_container">
    <div class="pro_cards col-3" *ngFor="let project of projects">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to loop through the CurrentEmployeeProjects inside the first loop, but that will return more than one result.

[image]
Right now the code above I have map through the projects.
So basically it should show the assign button if the employee doesnt have it, and show the unassign button if the employee has it.

Comment: Please share more code. Not enough information

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

Loop over allProjects and check if is in the currentEmployeeProject to add a new property "currentEmployedIsRoled"

```
this.allProjects.forEach(x=>{
   x.currentEmployedIsRoled=this.currentEmployeeProject
               .find(c=>c.pro_id==x.pro_id)?true:false;
})
```

Then use a `*ngIf="item.currentEmployedIsRoled"`